# getting application id and key

Tags: parse-platform, installation

ı am using putty to connect to my parse server.I tried to use the command cd apps/parse/docs
but it is giving me an error there is no such command.Is there any other command that serves the same function?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on windows, in cmd type input in this manner:

[absolute_path_to_executable] [[-ssh] | [-telnet] | [-rlogin] | [-raw]] [username]@[IP_address] [port]

i.e C:\Users\Elon\Documents\putty.exe --ssh elonaire@1.1.1.1 45

Finally press enter...

Comment: ı am runnıng wındows 10